# ember, The id X has already been used with another record for modelClass

Tags: javascript, ember.js

i have issues managing the deleted items in my Ember 2.18 store.

i have a "folder" model in my ember app (made with ember cli).
i create a folder named "FOLDER1".
I delete it, calling **destroyRecord**.
then after successfully destroying, i do a **store.unloadRecord(myFolder)** in the promise.
It calls my backend to delete it and updates the data store normally. The view updates accordingly, my folder seems to be deleted.

I can see the model is not present anymore in my Ember debug addon too, in Firefox, like expected.

But when i want to create an other folder named "FOLDER1", the ember data store throws this error

> "The id FOLDER1 has already been used with another record for
>   modelClass" from error.js.

like if it were not deleted.
(And the ember addon kind of crashes, in the data tab, i have the list of my models, counting my folders but cannot view the content of these models when i click on it.)

Did i miss something in the deletion process, should i do something else ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. This was a known issue in Ember Data 2.18 and was not fixed until Ember Data 3.2.

For more information, see https://github.com/emberjs/data/issues/5175